How can I approximate a product of rotation matrices?
Consider the following rotation matrices:
$$
R(\phi) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\phi) & 0 & -sin(\phi) \\
0 & 1& 0 \\
sin(\phi) & 0 & cos(\phi)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
R(\delta \phi) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\delta \phi) & 0 & -sin(\delta \phi) \\
0 & 1& 0 \\
sin(\delta \phi) & 0 & cos(\delta \phi)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P(\theta) =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\
0 & -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta))
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P(\delta \theta) =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos(\delta \theta) & sin(\delta \theta) \\
0 & -sin(\delta \theta) & cos(\delta \theta))
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
H(\psi) 
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\psi) & sin(\psi) & 0 \\
-sin(\psi) & cos(\psi) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
H(\delta \psi) 
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\delta \psi) & sin(\delta \psi) & 0 \\
-sin(\delta \psi) & cos(\delta \psi) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I need to evaluate the product:
$$
\Pi = (R(\phi)*P(\theta)*H(\psi))*(R(\delta \phi)*P(\delta \theta)*H(\delta \psi)) 
$$
where $\delta \phi$, $\delta \theta$ and $\delta \psi$ are very small.
I am looking for an approximation to the product above that minimizes the number of matrix multiplications.
Since infinitesimal rotations commute I get:
$$
\Pi \approx R(\phi)*P(\theta)*H(\psi)*H(\delta \psi)*R(\delta \phi)*P(\delta \theta) 
= R(\phi)*P(\theta)*H(\psi + \delta \psi)*R(\delta \phi)*P(\delta \theta)
$$
How can I minimize the number of matrix multiplications further?
If possible I am seeking an expression of the form:
$$
\Pi \approx R(?)*P(?)*H(?)
$$
For context consider an instrument inside an airplane that can detect objects relative to the plane as vector directions. The pilot wants to send the direction of such an object to a ground station.
However the plane is rotated with respect to the ground: $(\phi,\theta,\psi)$. Further the instrument was installed slightly wrong: $(\delta \phi,\delta \theta,\delta \psi)$.
Therefore:
$$
\vec{v_{ground}} = \Pi * \vec{v_{instrument}}
$$

What's the context for this? I wonder if a different representation of the rotations might be more helpful - have you tried with quaternions?

@ChrisLewis: I am not familiar with quaternions.
